# File Path with Symbol Causes Error

Tags: external-files, paths

I foolishly included a # (number symbol) in a file path. Whenever I reference this it generates the following error:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. [.../Paper#1/2016-02-14/paper1_2016-02-14.pdf}]
```

Is there a solution to this that is easier than renaming the folder, and consequently, changing all of the code within it to reflect that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{../../Paper#1/2016-02-14/paper1_2016-02-14.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping it?

Comment: Yeah, no dice, @Azor-Ahai

Comment: I don't understand why changing the file path would be a big deal. Depending on the nature of the deal and its bigness, you could use a symbolic link which TeX will be quite happy with. Assuming you are on a file system which supports such things (i.e. probably not Windows).

Comment: Its a non-negligible hassle because I have other code related to data cleaning and analysis which export figures and tables in the tex directory and I would rather not change all of that code if I don't have to. Its fine if I do, I am just hoping there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begingroup\catcode`\#=12
\newcommand\hashchar{}%check that is doesn't exist
\gdef\hashchar{#}
\endgroup

\input{paper\hashchar 1/test}


%or change the catcode locally:
\begingroup
\catcode`\#=12
\input{paper#1/test}
\endgroup


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your calls of `\includepdf` are never in the argument to another command, you can do it by absorbing the file name as a verbatim argument:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages,xparse,letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\originalincludepdf\includepdf
\RenewDocumentCommand\includepdf{O{}v}{\originalincludepdf[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{../../Paper#1/2016-02-14/paper1_2016-02-14.pdf}
\end{document}
```