# Store URLs in a macro without replaceing # and %

Tags: hyperref, urls

How can I store a URL in a macro if the URL has a `#` and/or a `%` in it?  The MWE below works fine for the first two, but not the third one.

[image]

### Notes:

- One solution is to replace the `#` with `\string#` and the `%` with `\%`, but wodering if there is an easier way.
- I realize that this may mess up the syntax highliting, but the `\csdef{}` section shown here will be in a separte `.def` file that will be be `\input{}`, so not an issue.

### Reference:

- [Accepting special characters in arguments passing them further](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499651/4301)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}

\csdef{url Title 1}{The Google}
\csdef{url Link 1}{http://www.google.com}

\csdef{url Title 2}{TeX.SE}
\csdef{url Link 2}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}

%\csdef{url Title 3}{Algebra and Trigonometry:~History of Trigonometry}
%\csdef{url Link 3}{https://books.google.com/books?id=4tFFDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT233&dq=history+of+trigonometry&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIzcj0-tnqAhXwFjQIHZ6XDLUQ6AEwAnoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false}

\def\MaxNUmberOfURLs{5}
\newcommand{\DisplayURLs}{%
    \textbf{List of URLs}
    \foreach \xCount in {1,...,\MaxNUmberOfURLs} {%
        \ifcsdef{url Title \xCount}{%
            \par\xCount:
            \href{\csuse{url Link \xCount}}{\csuse{url Title \xCount}}
        }{}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\DisplayURLs
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\csedef{url Link 3}{\detokenize{https://books.google.com/books?id=4tFFDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT233&dq=history+of+trigonometry&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIzcj0-tnqAhXwFjQIHZ6XDLUQ6AEwAnoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false}}` should work. *edit* Hrmpf: It works in the MWE, but breaks with `%`.

Comment: You asked, "How can I store a URL in a macro if the URL has a `# `and/or a `%` in it?" Isn't this precisely what the `\urldef` macro of the `url` package is supposed to do? E.g., `\urldef{\myURL}\url{https://books.google.com/books?id=4tFFDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT233&dq=history+of+trigonometry&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIzcj0-tnqAhXwFjQIHZ6XDLUQ6AEwAnoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false}`

Comment: @Mico: Did not know about that. You should post an asnwer as that might be a better alternative for some. For me, the `\csdefurl` defined in moewe's answer works great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hyperref`'s `\hyper@normalise` comes in extremely handy here. It can be used to sanitise the argument of a macro and allow it to accept special characters without escaping. (I think I first learned about `\hyper@normalise` from [Michael Ummels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4087/michael-ummels)' [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13073/35864) to [Getting those %#!^& signs in the footnote!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12855/35864.))

Just use it to define a new macro like `\newcommand*{\csdefurl}[1]{\hyper@normalise{\csdef{#1}}}`. (Note that the argument that is going to be "normalised" is *not* explicitly part of the definition. `\newcommand*{\csdefurl}[2]{\hyper@normalise{\csdef{#1}}{#2}}` would not work because then the argument is read with the unnormalised catcode setup.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\csdefurl}[1]{\hyper@normalise{\csdef{#1}}}
\makeatother

\csdef{url Title 1}{The Google}
\csdefurl{url Link 1}{http://www.google.com}

\csdef{url Title 2}{TeX.SE}
\csdefurl{url Link 2}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}

\csdef{url Title 3}{Algebra and Trigonometry:~History of Trigonometry}
\csdefurl{url Link 3}{https://example.com/~test/a%20and%20b.html#anchor}

\def\MaxNUmberOfURLs{5}
\newcommand{\DisplayURLs}{%
    \textbf{List of URLs}
    \foreach \xCount in {1,...,\MaxNUmberOfURLs} {%
        \ifcsdef{url Title \xCount}{%
            \par\xCount:
            \href{\csuse{url Link \xCount}}{\csuse{url Title \xCount}}
        }{}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\DisplayURLs
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the output. The third item reads "Algebra and Trigonometry: History of Trigonometry" and the little pop-up the PDF viewer shows on hover displays "https://example.com/~test/a%20and%20b.html#anchor"]

---

Some more testing reveals that

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\csdefurl@i}{}
\newrobustcmd*{\csdefurl}[1]{%
  \def\csdefurl@i{\csdef{#1}}%
  \hyper@normalise\csdefurl@i}
\makeatother
```

might be safer.

Compare this definition to the one above in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\csdefurl@i}{}
\newrobustcmd*{\csdefurl}[1]{%
  \def\csdefurl@i{\csdef{#1}}%
  \hyper@normalise\csdefurl@i}
\makeatother

\csdef{ürl Title 1}{The Google}
\csdefurl{ürl Link 1}{http://www.google.com}

\csdef{ürl Title 2}{TeX.SE}
\csdefurl{ürl Link 2}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}

\csdef{ürl Title 3}{Algebra and Trigonometry:~History of Trigonometry}
\csdefurl{ürl Link 3}{https://example.com/~test/a%20and%20b.html#anchor}

\def\MaxNUmberOfURLs{5}
\newcommand{\DisplayURLs}{%
    \textbf{List of URLs}
    \foreach \xCount in {1,...,\MaxNUmberOfURLs} {%
        \ifcsdef{ürl Title \xCount}{%
            \par\xCount:
            \href{\csuse{ürl Link \xCount}}{\csuse{ürl Title \xCount}}
        }{}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\DisplayURLs
\end{document}
```

where we have the non-ASCII `ürl` instead of `url`.

Answer (score 7):

You asked,

> "How can I store a URL in a macro if the URL has a `#` and/or a `%` in it?"

The `\urldef` directive of the `url` package lets you create precisely such macros. E.g.,

```
\urldef{\myURL}\url{https://books.google.com/books?id=4tFFDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT233&dq=history+of+trigonometry&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIzcj0-tnqAhXwFjQIHZ6XDLUQ6AEwAnoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false}
```

Note the syntax: `\urldef{<macroname>}\url{<URLstring>}`. Observe taht `\url{<URLstring>}` must *not* be enclosed in curly braces.

`\myUrl` may be used in the argument of `\footnote` directives.