# Write definition of command with arguments to file

Tags: macros, expansion

I am trying to create a command that can write command definitions into a file, while also defining them. So I want a command `\teecommand` that takes one argument. This argument should be written to a file as is, and also expanded.

My current attempt is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newwrite\commandsfile
\immediate\openout\commandsfile=commands.tex

\DeclareDocumentCommand\teecommand{s m}{%
    \write\commandsfile{\unexpanded{#2}}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{}{#2} % Only expand the command if no * is given
}

\teecommand{\newcommand{\foo}{this is foo}}
\teecommand{\newcommand{\foobar}[1]{this is bar: #1}}

\begin{document}
\foo\\
\foobar{123}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this, as expected:
[image]

The file `commands.tex` is also created, with the following content:

```
\newcommand {\foo }{this is foo}
\newcommand {\foobar }[1]{this is bar: ##1}
```

The first line is as expected, but the second line has a doubled up `#`. This unfortunately breaks the application trying to parse the `.tex` file (the MathJax based equation previewer from [LaTeX Workshop](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop)).

**Question:** *How can I fix the command `\teecommand` to give me the correct output with `#1` instead of `##1` for argument placeholders?*

*Note:* I am using `memoir` in the example above as this is what I need to use in my actual document, and I want to avoid having a solution that is incompatible with it.

Comment: you only need xparse with older latex formats, the commands are pre-defined in latex in current releases.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the info, updated the question

Comment: (even though the questions are slightly different, I decide to flag anyway because all of the answers there should be applicable here with minor modification + I think it's less desirable to duplicate the answer content here, would be harder to update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a regex replacement of `#` with the same character, but with category code “other”.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\iow_new:N \g_lukas_teecommand_iow
\iow_open:Nn \g_lukas_teecommand_iow { \c_sys_jobname_str.cmd }

\NewDocumentCommand\teecommand{s m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \cP\# } { \cO\# } \l_tmpa_tl
    \iow_now:NV \g_lukas_teecommand_iow \l_tmpa_tl
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{#2} % Only expand the command if no * is given
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_now:Nn { NV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\teecommand{\newcommand{\foo}{this is foo}}
\teecommand{\newcommand{\foobar}[1]{this is bar: #1}}
\teecommand{\newcommand{\fooagain}[2]{this is again: #1 and #2}}

\stop
```

The contents of the written file (I changed the name in order not to risk clobbering my files):

```
\newcommand {\foo }{this is foo}
\newcommand {\foobar }[1]{this is bar: #1}
\newcommand {\fooagain }[2]{this is again: #1 and #2}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution, albeit an ugly one (please let me know if you can think of a better solution that doesn't need a temporary file):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newwrite\commandsfile
\immediate\openout\commandsfile=commands.tex


\makeatletter
\newwrite\commandtempfile
\newcommand{\teecommand}{\begingroup\catcode`\#=12\relax\@teecommand}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\@teecommand{s m}{%
    \endgroup%
    \write\commandsfile{\unexpanded{#2}}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{}{%
        \immediate\openout\commandtempfile=currentcommand.tmp%
        \immediate\write\commandtempfile{\unexpanded{#2}}%
        \immediate\closeout\commandtempfile%
        \input{currentcommand.tmp}
    }
}
\makeatother

\teecommand{\newcommand{\foo}{this is foo}}
\teecommand{\newcommand{\foobar}[1]{this is bar: #1}}

\begin{document}
\foo\\
\foobar{123}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to use the trick from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302163/escape-hash-tag-in-strings-passed-to-newcommands) to prevent `#` from being expanded. The issue is now that I want to selectively expand it to actually define the command. To do that, I write the command to a temporary file that I immediately input again. *A nicer solution would really be appreciated*

Comment: Instead of temporary file you can use `\scantokens`. `\scantokens` is like unexpanded-writing the tokens of its "argument" to text-file and reading back that text-file, hereby tokenizing the things that are read outgoing from current category code régime.

Comment: E.g., something like `\NewDocumentCommand{\teecommand}{s +v}{\begingroup\newlinechar=\endlinechar\relax\immediate\write\commandsfile{\unexpanded{#2}\csname @percentchar\endcsname}\endgroup\IfBooleanTF{#1}{}{\begingroup\newlinechar=\endlinechar\relax\scantokens{\endgroup#2\relax}}}`