# More efficient implementation using expl3

Tags: expl3, xparse

This is a follow-up question to my previous one on [using special characters in user-defined commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400981/using-special-characters-in-arguments-of-user-defined-commands). I have extended the command `\Char{}` to take an optional parameter for a fixed with. `\Char{}` is supposed to work in text mode and math mode.

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \Char { o m } 
{
  \IfNoValueTF {#1}
  {
    \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_to_str:n {#2} }
    {
      {              } { \mbox{$\varepsilon$}           }
      { ##           } { \mbox{\texttt{\#}}             }
      { \c_tilde_str } { \mbox{\textscale{.87}{$\Box$}} }
    }
    { \mbox{\texttt{#2}} }
  }
  {
    \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_to_str:n {#2} }
    {
      {              } { \makebox[#1]{$\varepsilon$}           }
      { ##           } { \makebox[#1]{\texttt{\#}}             }
      { \c_tilde_str } { \makebox[#1]{\textscale{.87}{$\Box$}} }
    }
    { \makebox[#1]{\texttt{#2}} }
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Char{}\Char{~}\Char{#}\Char{x}
$\Char{}\Char{~}\Char{#}\Char{x}$
\Char[1em]{}\Char[1em]{~}\Char[1em]{#}\Char[1em]{x}
$\Char[1em]{}\Char[1em]{~}\Char[1em]{#}\Char[1em]{x}$

\end{document}
```

produces the desired result

[image: desired result]

However, is there a better way to implement this functionality based on expl3?

Comment: LaTeX3 is still not “complete” regarding document commands, so many things are still not done yet.

Comment: @Manuel Does this mean I should leave the implementation as it is for now accepting the mixture of LaTeX3 and LaTeX2e?

Comment: Yes. Only may be reduce duplication of code (e.g., only have one `\str_case` rather than having two of them, and may be moving `\texttt` out of the cases if possible, i.e., `\makebox{\texttt{\str_case .. }}`).

Comment: it depends if you want to optimise run time or optimise your developer time, I'd consider using `O{\width}` instead of `o` and then you don't need the IfNoValue test you can just use the `\makebox` form always as `\makebox[\width]{zzz}` is the same as `\mbox{\zzz}` just marginally less efficient. but it would halve the size of your definition and save you checking the two halves were in sync as you add more cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this as a starter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \Char { o m } 
{
    \IfNoValueTF { #1 } { \makebox } { \makebox [#1] }
    {
    \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_to_str:n {#2} }
    {
      {              } { $\varepsilon$           }
      { ##           } { \texttt{\#}             }
      { \c_tilde_str } { \textscale{.87}{$\Box$} }
    }
    { \texttt{#2} }
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Char{}\Char{~}\Char{#}\Char{x}
$\Char{}\Char{~}\Char{#}\Char{x}$
\Char[1em]{}\Char[1em]{~}\Char[1em]{#}\Char[1em]{x}
$\Char[1em]{}\Char[1em]{~}\Char[1em]{#}\Char[1em]{x}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the fact that `\makebox[\width]{...}` is a slightly slower version of `\mbox{...}`, we can trade a bit of efficiency with avoidance of code duplication.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \Char { O{\width} m }
 {
  \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_to_str:n {#2} }
   {
    {              } { \makebox[#1]{$\varepsilon$}           }
    { ##           } { \makebox[#1]{\texttt{\#}}             }
    { \c_tilde_str } { \makebox[#1]{\textscale{.87}{$\Box$}} }
   }
   { \makebox[#1]{\texttt{#2}} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Char{}\Char{~}\Char{#}\Char{x}
$\Char{}\Char{~}\Char{#}\Char{x}$
\Char[1em]{}\Char[1em]{~}\Char[1em]{#}\Char[1em]{x}
$\Char[1em]{}\Char[1em]{~}\Char[1em]{#}\Char[1em]{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]