# Problem using a sequence in expl3

Tags: expl3, xparse

I would like to write a command `\TransTM` that expands, for example, `\TransTM{a, x, R | b, y, L}` to `\shortstack{a;~x,~R \\ b;~y,~L}`.

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \TransTM { m  }
  { \edge_label:cn {edge_item_tm:nnn} {#1} }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \edge_label:cn #1 #2
{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { | } { #2 } 
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \edge_item:cn {#1} {##1} }
  \shortstack{ \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { \\ } }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \edge_item:cn #1 #2
{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #2 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { {##1} }
  \use:c { #1 } x x x % \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \edge_item_tm:nnn #1 #2 #3
{
  #1;~#2,~#3
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, R}

\end{document}
```

works only partly, since I have managed to split the argument at `|` on the first level, but not at `,` on the second level. `\seq_use:Nn` in `\edge_item:cn` is commented out and replaced by the hard-coded `x x x` because it produces an error.

What is wrong in attempting to split the argument on the second level?

Note: There will be different variants in future. This is why I pass the name of the function `edge_item_tm:nnn` as an argument. Another document-level command `\TransFA{a | b | c}`, for example, is supposed to expand to `\shortstack{a \\ b \\ c}`. The difference will be only in the structure of the parts between the `|` tokens.

**Addendum**

It seems I oversimplified the above MWE. The following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \Char { O{\width} m } 
{
  \makebox[#1] 
  {
    \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_to_str:n {#2} }
    {
      {              } { $\varepsilon$           }
      { ##           } { \texttt{\#}             }
      { \c_tilde_str } { \textscale{.87}{$\Box$} }
    }
    { \texttt{#2} }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \TransTM { m }
  { \__edge_label_tm:n {#1} }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__edge_label_tm:n #1 
{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { | } { #1 } 
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \SplitItemTM \exp_not:n { {##1} } }
  \shortstack{ \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { \\ } }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \SplitItemTM { >{\SplitArgument{2}{,}} m }
  { \__edge_item_tm:nnn #1 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__edge_item_tm:nnn #1 #2 #3 
{
  \Char[.63em]{#1};\;\Char[.63em]{#2},\,\Char{#3}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TransTM{a, x, L} \qquad
\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, L} \qquad
\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, L | ~, ~, R}

\end{document}
```

yields the desired result.

[image: desired result]

However, it misuses `\NewDocumentCommand` since `\SplitItemTM` belongs to the implementation and not to the user interface. What would be the right way to replace `\SplitItemTM` by an internal function?

Comment: Isn't `\shortstack` a `stackengine` macro?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, `\shortstack` is the "built-in" version. `\Shortstack` and `\Longstack` are defined in `stackengine`. However, the stacking part works as expected.

Comment: Yes, I confused it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off: you should not define with `\cs_new_protected:Npn` a function with signature `:cn`.

I take that your input is of the form `\TransTM{a, x, R | b, y, L | c, m, n, p}` and you want to isolate the first item in each `|`-separated part for using a semicolon after it.

First split the argument at `|` and perform a mapping adding an auxiliary function around each item. This auxiliary macro will act when the row in `\shortstack` will be printed: isolate the first item, print it followed by a semicolon and space, then deliver the rest of the sequence items separated by comma and space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\TransTM}{m}
 {
  \matthias_edge_label:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__matthias_edge_labels_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__matthias_edge_labels_out_seq
\seq_new:N \l__matthias_edge_label_seq
\tl_new:N \l__matthias_edge_label_head_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \matthias_edge_label:n
 {
  % first let's split at |
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__matthias_edge_labels_in_seq { | } { #1 }
  % populate the sequence for output
  \seq_set_map:NNn
   \l__matthias_edge_labels_out_seq
   \l__matthias_edge_labels_in_seq
   { \__matthias_edge_label:n { \exp_not:n { ##1 } } }
  % deliver it
  \shortstack{ \seq_use:Nn \l__matthias_edge_labels_out_seq { \\ } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__matthias_edge_label:n
 {
  % split the argument at commas
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__matthias_edge_label_seq { , } { #1 }
  % remove the first item
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__matthias_edge_label_seq \l__matthias_edge_label_head_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__matthias_edge_label_head_tl
  ;~
  \seq_use:Nn \l__matthias_edge_label_seq { ,~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, R}
\qquad 
\TransTM{a, x, R | b, y, L | c, m, n, p}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, let's see what went wrong with your approach. When you do

```
\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, R}
```

the sequence `\l_tmpb_seq` will contain the items

```
{\edge_item:cn {edge_item_tm:nnn} {a, x, L}}
{\edge_item:cn {edge_item_tm:nnn} {b, y, R}}
```

(outer braces for clarity, but not really there). When the sequence is delivered, you get

```
\shortstack{%
  \edge_item:cn {edge_item_tm:nnn} {a, x, L}\\%
  \edge_item:cn {edge_item_tm:nnn} {b, y, R}%
}
```

(lines split for ease of reading). Now your idea is to split the items in the second argument at commas, and apply a three argument function. But if you do

```
\use:c{edge_item_tm:nnn} \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { }
```

the first argument to `\edge_item_tm:nnn` will be `\seq_use:Nn`, because this hasn't yet been expanded.

This can be done, however, but I don't recommend this approach. In any case, the `c` arguments are out of place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \TransTM { m  }
  { \edge_label:Nn \edge_item_tm:nnn {#1} }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \edge_label:Nn #1 #2
{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { | } { #2 } 
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \edge_item:Nn #1 {##1} }
  \shortstack{ \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { \\ } }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \edge_item:Nn #1 #2
{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #2 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { {##1} }
  \exp_last_unbraced:Nf #1 \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \edge_item_tm:nnn #1 #2 #3
{
  #1;~#2,~#3
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, R}

\end{document}
```

## ADDENDUM

You're right in thinking that `\SplitItemTM` doesn't belong there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \Char { O{\width} m } 
 {
  \makebox[#1]{ \edge_char:n { #2 } }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \TransTM { m }
 {
  \edge_label:n {#1}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__edge_labels_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__edge_labels_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \edge_char:n
 {
  \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_to_str:n {#1} }
   {
    {              } { $\varepsilon$           }
    { ##           } { \texttt{\#}             }
    { \c_tilde_str } { \scalebox{.87}{$\Box$}  }
   }
  { \texttt{#1} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \edge_char:n { f }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \edge_label:n
 {
  \group_begin:
  % this because otherwise boxes would not print
  \char_set_active_eq:nN { `\~ } \c_tilde_str

  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__edge_labels_in_seq { | } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn
   \l__edge_labels_out_seq
   \l__edge_labels_in_seq
   { \edge_item:n { \exp_not:n { ##1 } } }
  \shortstack
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l__edge_labels_out_seq { \\ }
   }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \edge_item:n
 {
  \edge_char:f { \clist_item:nn { #1 } {1} } ; ~
  \edge_char:f { \clist_item:nn { #1 } {2} } , ~
  \edge_char:f { \clist_item:nn { #1 } {3} }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TransTM{a, x, L} \qquad
\TransTM{a, , L | b, #, L} \qquad
\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, L | ~, ~, R}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Is there any reason to prefer `\seq_set_split:Nnn ` over `\seq_set_from_clist:Nn` to split the comma separated list?

Comment: @Andrew Not really, but `\seq_set_split:Nnn` is more general.

Comment: @egreg Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. However, I was not yet able to achieve my goal. Could you please have a look at my addendum?

Comment: IIRC `\seq_set_split:Nnn` does not remove spaces around items (and one set of braces) and it does not remove empty entries.  In contrast, `\seq_set_from_clist:Nn` treats its arg as a clist hence does the normalization I just said.

Comment: @Matthias Had a look. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg That is exactly what I was looking for. The second example needs to be `\TransTM{a, {}, L | b, #, L}` to print the epsilon at the correct position, which is perfectly adequate for my purposes.

Comment: @Matthias Perhaps using `?` or `-` instead of empty is better.

Answer (score 2):

A `listofitems` alternative-to-L3 version.  EDITED to remove the need for argument expandability, which is demonstrated by using the unexpandable `\ddag` in the argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand{\addtotoks}[2]{#1\expandafter{\the#1#2}}
\newcommand{\xxaddtotoks}[2]{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\addtotoks%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{#2}}
\newtoks\zztoks
\newcommand\TransTM[1]{%
  \setsepchar{{|}/,}%
  \readlist*\zz{#1}%
  \zztoks{}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\zz[]{%
   \if\xcnt=1\else\addtotoks\zztoks{\\}\fi
   \xxaddtotoks\zztoks{\zz[\xcnt,1];~}%
   \xxaddtotoks\zztoks{\zz[\xcnt,2],~}%
   \xxaddtotoks\zztoks{\zz[\xcnt,3]}%
  }%
  \expandafter\shortstack\expandafter{\the\zztoks}%
}
\begin{document}
\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, R}\quad%
\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, R | c, y, \ddag}
\end{document}
```

or if one does not like token lists, then with `\def`s (via `\g@addto@macro`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\TransTM[1]{%
  \setsepchar{{|}/,}%
  \readlist*\zz{#1}%
  \def\zzz{}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\zz[]{%
   \if\xcnt=1\else\g@addto@macro\zzz{\\}\fi
   \addzzz{\zz[\xcnt,1];~}%
   \addzzz{\zz[\xcnt,2],~}%
   \addzzz{\zz[\xcnt,3]}%
  }%
  \expandafter\shortstack\expandafter{\zzz}%
}
\newcommand\addzzz[1]{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\g@addto@macro%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\zzz\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, R}\quad%
\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, R | c, y, \ddag}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A version that shows that `\Char` can be used with this approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,xparse,relsize,amssymb}
\newcommand{\addtotoks}[2]{#1\expandafter{\the#1#2}}
\newcommand{\xxaddtotoks}[2]{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\addtotoks%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{#2}}
\def\ZZ{\Char[.5em]{~}}%
\newtoks\zztoks
\newcommand\TransTM[1]{%
  \setsepchar{{|}/,}%
  \readlist*\zz{#1}%
  \zztoks{}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\zz[]{%
   \if\xcnt=1\else\addtotoks\zztoks{\\}\fi
   \xxaddtotoks\zztoks{\zz[\xcnt,1];~}%
   \xxaddtotoks\zztoks{\zz[\xcnt,2],~}%
   \xxaddtotoks\zztoks{\zz[\xcnt,3]}%
  }%
  \texttt{\expandafter\shortstack\expandafter{\the\zztoks}}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \Char { O{\width} m } 
{
  \makebox[#1] 
  {
    \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_to_str:n {#2} }
    {
      {              } { $\varepsilon$           }
      { ##           } { \texttt{\#}             }
      { \c_tilde_str } { \textscale{.87}{$\Box$} }
    }
    { \texttt{#2} }
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, R}\quad%
\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, R | \ZZ, y, \ddag}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. Could that be extended to an arbitary number of items on the first level? `\TransTM{a, x, L}` and `\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, R}` and `\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, R | c, y, L}` and so on are expected to work.

Comment: @Matthias See edit.

Comment: @StevenBSegletes Amazing. The whole functionality in a couple of lines of code.

Comment: @Matthias This does require, though, that the argument pieces are expandable.  If that may not always be the case, I could rework without the `\edef`.

Comment: @StevenBSegletes In real life, the argument pieces need to be wrapped in `\Char{}` according to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401244/more-efficient-implementation-using-expl3). There may be calls such as `\TransTM{~, x, L | ~, ~, R}`. Could that cause any trouble using your approach?

Comment: @Matthias With my edits to remove the `\edef`, there should be no problems anymore if an argument is unexpandable, since now the actual tokens of the argument list are preserved intact.

Comment: @StevenBSegletes What is the right place to call `\Char` according to my addendum within your implementation of `\TransTM`?

Comment: @Matthias I can invoke `\TransTM{a, x, L | b, y, R | \Char[.63em]{~}, y, \ddag}`, once I supply the `xparse,relsize,amssymb` packages and some of your macros.